# systemevents.sessionended is not being caught or fired

Tags: c#

Please in my code i try to catch win32.systemevents.sessionended event to procede with saving of my app data by the end of session in case the app is not closed manually .. some time ago this has been workin and now that i had my project grown a lil it is not any more..? i have tried to find something meaningfull for few days but found nothing really.. when i try to catch another systemevent like MonitorResolutionChanged it works well but this one not. I have also tried to register within the mainWindow (app form ..), nothing :-(    Please any idea?
I think all the relevant information should be in the beginning till void Main but i put it all in case you would need or want to see more .. Thanx a lot  Tomas 
My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using MovablePython; // my own class within this project
using Avn; //my own referenced assembly 

namespace DirDist
{
     class Program
    {
        private static string appGuid = "Cddbserviceman";
        private static System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu nIMenu;
        internal static System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon1;
        private static MenuItem showItem;
        public static MenuItem justCDsItem;
        private static MenuItem searchItem;
        private static MenuItem settingsItem;
        private static MenuItem quitItem;

        internal static Form1 mainWindow;
        private static Hotkey hk;
        internal static Registration.LicenceState mode; // app mode - registered/trial/blocked/demaged ..
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        { 
            using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, appGuid))
            {
                if (!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("CDDB is already running on your machine \n  (Check status bar for access ..)");
                    return;
                }
                GC.Collect();

                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                mode = Registration.Startup();

                Program.mainWindow = new Form1();
                mainWindow.Activate();
                //mainWindow.Validate();
                //mainWindow.Update();
                mainWindow.Visible = false;
                PutIcon();

                //Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded += SystemEvents_SessionEnded;
                Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnded);//**zkousime zda funguje pro hibernaci ..
                RegisterHotKey(true);   
                Application.Run();
            }   
        }

        static void SystemEvents_SessionEnded(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("SessionEnded fired");

            RegisterHotKey(false);

            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
            notifyIcon1.Dispose();
            notifyIcon1 = null;


            if (!mainWindow.dBSaved) mainWindow.SaveDb(Form1.settings.dBPath);
            if (mainWindow.index != null) mainWindow.SaveIndex(Form1.settings.indexPath);
            Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded -= new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnded);
            mainWindow.Close();
        }

        // zaregistruje globalni hotkey ctrl+shift+F Pro hledani
        private static void RegisterHotKey(bool active)
        {
            if (!active)
            {
                if (hk != null) hk.Unregister();
            }
            else
            {
                if(hk ==null) hk = new Hotkey();

                hk.KeyCode = Keys.F;
                //hk.Windows = true;
                hk.Shift = true;
                hk.Control = true;
                //hk.Pressed += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Windows+1 pressed!"); };
                hk.Pressed += delegate { searchItemClick(new object(), new EventArgs()); };

                if (hk.GetCanRegister(mainWindow)) hk.Register(mainWindow);
                else ; // just do nothing
            }
        }

        private static void PutIcon()
        {
            if (notifyIcon1 == null)
            {   
                showItem = new MenuItem ("&Show interface", new System.EventHandler (showInfaceClick));
                justCDsItem = new MenuItem ("&Jus'CDs",new System.EventHandler ( justCDsClick));
                justCDsItem.Checked = Form1.settings.justCDs;
                searchItem = new MenuItem("Search CDDB",new System.EventHandler (searchItemClick));
                searchItem.Shortcut = Shortcut.CtrlShiftF;
                searchItem.ShowShortcut = true;
                settingsItem = new MenuItem("Settings", new System.EventHandler(settingsItemClick));
                quitItem = new MenuItem("&Quit", new System.EventHandler(quitItemClick));

                nIMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu(new MenuItem[5] { showItem, justCDsItem, searchItem,settingsItem, quitItem });


                notifyIcon1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
                notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = nIMenu;
                notifyIcon1.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\Icon1.ico");
                //notifyIcon1.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
                //System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase ) + "Icon1.ico");
                //notifyIcon1.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("Icon1.ico");
                notifyIcon1.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(notifyIcon1_DoubleClick);
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        /* private static void notifyIcon1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs mea)
         * aby to fungovalo je treba upravit contextmenu na contextmenustrip a taky ty items .. az nakonec
         * je tu kolem uz rozdelana priprava ..
        {
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(2000,AppName,"Active",ToolTipIcon.None);
        } */

        // clicks on NotificationIcon context menu ..
        private static void showInfaceClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mainWindow.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            mainWindow.Show();
        }

        private static void justCDsClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.settings.justCDs = mainWindow.checkBox1.Checked = justCDsItem.Checked = !Form1.settings.justCDs;
            if (mainWindow.Visible) mainWindow.Update();
        }

        private static void searchItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mainWindow.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1 ;
            //this.Size = new Size(this.Width, SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height);
            mainWindow.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width - mainWindow.Width, SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height - mainWindow.Height);
            //mainWindow.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(880, 500);
            mainWindow.Show();
        }

        private static void settingsItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mainWindow.tabPage3_GotFocus(new Object(), new EventArgs());
            mainWindow.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2;
            mainWindow.Show();
        }

        public static void quitItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DialogResult.Cancel == MessageBox.Show("Really exit application and stop scanning?",Form1.AppName,MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Question)) return;
            if (!mainWindow.dBSaved) mainWindow.SaveDb(Form1.settings.dBPath);
            //if (mainWindow.index != null) mainWindow.SaveIndex(Form1.settings.indexPath);
            if (Form1.settings.fileIndex) mainWindow.SaveIndex(Form1.settings.indexPath);
            mainWindow.Close();
            mainWindow = null;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
            Application.Exit();
        }

        static void notifyIcon1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            //if (!mainWindow.Visible) mainWindow.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; else mainWindow.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            //if (!mainWindow.Visible) mainWindow.Show(); else mainWindow.Hide();
            if (!mainWindow.Visible) mainWindow.Visible = true; else mainWindow.Visible = false;      
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

OK. So here is the catch and solution . In Windows it is not determined whether win32.systemevents.sessionended shall be risen or form.close() will be called first by operating system. moreover it seems that if form.close() is called first then sessionended is omited even though form is not closed and disposed due to canceling closing process. in my system this behaviour changed after i ran some registry cleaning software. anyway understanding this we have to take care of both possible scenarios.
1. catch win32.systemevents.sessionended (or sessionending) event whatever suits our needs  better and be

```
 .
    .
   [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    { 
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnded);

            Program.mainWindow = new Form1();
            mainWindow.Activate();
            mainWindow.Visible = false;
            PutIcon();           
            RegisterHotKey(true);   
            Application.Run();
        }   
    }

    public static void SystemEvents_SessionEnded(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do whatever needed and exit application ..
        RegisterHotKey(false);
        notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        notifyIcon1.Dispose();
        notifyIcon1 = null;


        if (!mainWindow.dBSaved) mainWindow.SaveDb(Form1.settings.dBPath);
        if (mainWindow.index != null) mainWindow.SaveIndex(Form1.settings.indexPath);
        Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded -= new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnded);

        if (mainWindow != null)
        {
            mainWindow.Dispose();
            mainWindow = null;
        }
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

2. properly override form.OnClosing() because this is being called when form is closing either manually by user or by system when shuting down, loging off etc. or create hanler for main form.Closing:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        this.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(this.Form1_Closing);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Closing(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
            {
                if (systemShutdown) Program.SystemEvents_SessionEnded(this, new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventArgs(Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndReasons.SystemShutdown));
                else
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    this.Hide();
                }
            }
```

just want to mention that message pump must be runnig in order to sessionended be risen. Application.run() accomplishes that.

in my case as you can see i had to dig even deeper as i had closing redirected just to hide the app not to close it ( i just hide the app to notification irea icon and close it manually when i need .. ) and so i had to use some kind of way to specify the situation when this is called because sender is unfortunatelly and unexpectedly always this ..? 
this is done by overring WndProc and catching propper message .here you can listen pretty much to everything inside windows ( like disc inserted / removed )but it is hooked only to a form and implementation gets often not so simple as you have to manully define various values and structs and compare against those values .. other then that its pretty simple:

```
private static int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x11;
private static bool systemShutdown = false;
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg==WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
    {
        systemShutdown = true;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);

}
```

this was found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx

Thinking a bit further we can possibly omit point 1 as system shall probably always try to call mainForm.close() but i keep it as i can not be certain about windows behaviour once it runs those things in different order again .. and also it is the mainly suggested solution for reacting to system shut down ..

hope this is helpfull for someone. greets from prague tomas

Comment: Your option 2 is useful for me, I had my issue fixed. I merged sessionending event in form closing event.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that you could try

For a shutdown, override the OnShutdown method:

```
protected override void OnShutdown()
{
    //your code here
    base.OnShutdown();
}
```

For a logoff:

First, add an event handler to Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded in the Service Constructor:

```
public MyService()
{
    InitializeComponent;
    Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnded);
}
```

Then add the handler:

```
void SystemEvents_SessionEnded(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventArgs e)
{
    //your code here
}
```

This should catch any ended session, including the console itself (the one running the services).

Comment: Thanx Dj Kraze, me also dj (Spejbl). anyway. Your answer seems like servis related but my code is a Windows.Forms app am I missing something? other than i have more or less tried to the same thing as you suggest within my main form constructor. could it be the difference registring the handler before InicializeComponent call ..? i am not sure where did i put it, before i guess .. anyway my lil thing stopes all windows to terminate ..?

Comment: I would guess that `OnShutdown` refers to [`ServiceBase.OnShutdown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onshutdown(v=vs.110).aspx).