# Calling 'ShutdownBlockReasonCreate' function does not prevent the user from shutting down the system

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke, shutdown

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Shutdown/shutting-down) article says:

> If an application must block a potential system shutdown, it can call
>   the ShutdownBlockReasonCreate function. The caller provides a reason
>   string that will be displayed to the user.

And in the [ShutdownBlockReasonCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasoncreate) documentation it clearly indicates that a dialog window with the reason string will be displayed to the user when attempting to shutdown:

> Indicates that the system cannot be shut down and sets a reason string
>   to be displayed to the user if system shutdown is initiated

And the appearance of that dialog window is confirmed in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151002-00/?p=91461) discussion:

> The user could click "Shut down anyway". Besides, the system assumes
>   "Shut down anyway" if the user takes no action within some number of
>   seconds.

However, after I call **ShutdownBlockReasonCreate** passing the main window handle of the current application, assuring that the function succeed and double assuring it by calling [ShutdownBlockReasonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasonquery) function to retrieve the reason string, it does not prevent the user from shutting down the system and no dialog window is shown.

Why it has no effect on my system?, and how do I solve this issue?.

I'm running on Windows 10 x64 with an Administrator (built-in) account, and the code that I'm using is from [this](https://github.com/dahall/Vanara/blob/138accc380839d6d8b12b68deea1149d3acaf7af/WIndows.Forms/Contexts/PreventShutdownContext.cs) GitHub repository:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Vanara.PInvoke;
using static Vanara.PInvoke.User32;

namespace Vanara.Windows.Forms.Forms
{
    /// <summary>Used to define a set of operations within which any shutdown request will be met with a reason why this application is blocking it.</summary>
    /// <remarks>This is to be used in either a 'using' statement or for the life of the application.
    /// <para>To use for the life of the form, define a class field:
    public class PreventShutdownContext : IDisposable
    {
        private HandleRef href;

        /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PreventShutdownContext"/> class.</summary>
        /// <param name="window">The <see cref="Form"/> or <see cref="Control"/> that contains a valid window handle.</param>
        /// <param name="reason">The reason the application must block system shutdown. Because users are typically in a hurry when shutting down the system, they may spend only a few seconds looking at the shutdown reasons that are displayed by the system. Therefore, it is important that your reason strings are short and clear.</param>
        public PreventShutdownContext(Control window, string reason)
        {
            href = new HandleRef(window, window.Handle);
            Reason = reason;
        }

        /// <summary>The reason the application must block system shutdown. Because users are typically in a hurry when shutting down the system, they may spend only a few seconds looking at the shutdown reasons that are displayed by the system. Therefore, it is important that your reason strings are short and clear.</summary>
        /// <value>The reason string.</value>
        public string Reason
        {
            get
            {
                if (!ShutdownBlockReasonQuery(href.Handle, out var reason))
                    Win32Error.ThrowLastError();
                return reason;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == null) value = string.Empty;
                if (ShutdownBlockReasonQuery(href.Handle, out var _))
                    ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(href.Handle);
                if (!ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(href.Handle, value))
                    Win32Error.ThrowLastError();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.</summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(href.Handle);
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
[DllImport(Lib.User32, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(HWND hWnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string reason);

[DllImport(Lib.User32, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool ShutdownBlockReasonQuery(HWND hWnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pwszBuff, ref uint pcchBuff);

[DllImport(Lib.User32, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(HWND hWnd);
```

With an usage like this:

```
using (new PreventShutdownContext(this, "This app is super busy right now."))
{
  // Do something that can't be interrupted...
}
```

I tried the code as is, with its P/Invoke definitions, and also a little modification of the code on which I'm using **IntPtr** structure for window handles instead of that custom [HWND](https://github.com/dahall/Vanara/blob/93a4982951715dc6784a37546bad5cc4a473b0d7/PInvoke/Shared/Handles.cs#L1745) structure, and passing to it the main window handle of the application as I specified in a commentary above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is by design.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasoncreate) (as well as the topic you referenced) can be slightly misleading.

> Indicates that the system cannot be shut down and sets a reason string to be displayed to the user if system shutdown is initiated.
>
> If an application must block a potential system shutdown, it can call the `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` function.

This function actually only sets the **message string** for your application. This function doesn't **prevent** your application from being closed.

To implement the shutdown block, just follow the steps described in the article you referenced. You need to react to the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message and return `FALSE` (0).
For reference, see also the [`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shutdown/wm-queryendsession) documentation.

You might also find interesting [this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Shutdown/shutdown-changes-for-windows-vista) - it describes the changes introduced with Windows Vista and contains the best practices how to implement the shutdown logic.

By the way, there will be no special "dialog window" about your application. The standard Windows shutdown UI will be shown (it differs depending on the OS version). Your application will appear in the *"Applications that prevent the shutdown"* list with the message you register using the `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` function - but only if it returns `FALSE` for the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message.

---

### Update

If the above solution (`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`) doesn't solve the issue, it might be caused by a system setting that just ignores this mechanism.

As @ElektroStudios discovered in their research:

- If the user has the `AutoEndTasks` registry value set (found in `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop` registry key), then the shutdown does not show any UI to let the user cancel shutdown. So it's useless to create a "cancel shutdown reason" in these circumstances, because the app will be forced to close instantly in any case (to continue the shutdown). For reference, read [this MS Docs topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc978604(v=technet.10)).
- In order to make this thing work as expected, the `AutoEndTasks` registry value must be 0 (zero); otherwise, any app that attempts to prevent shutdown will be terminated and no UI will be shown at shutdown.
- The `AutoEndTasks` value can be added to the `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop` key that overrides the value defined in the `HKCU` hive and `HKU\{SID}`. This means, if `AutoEndTasks` is `false` (0) in `HKCU` but is `true` (1) in `HKU\.DEFAULT`, then the app will not prevent the system from shutting down and no shutdown UI will be shown. If `AutoEndTasks` is `false` in `HKU\.DEFAULT` but is true in `HKCU`, then the app will prevent the system from shutting down and the shutdown UI will be shown.
- Also a good point about this is that the `AutoEndTasks` value does not require to restart/log-off the system to take effect. So, once it is set to `false` in the proper key (e.g. `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop`), the app will prevent the system from shutdown, and we can revert this value to its previous state when we finish to use the functionality.

Comment: First of all thanks for answer, but this is desperate, see, in my system responding 0 to **WM_QUERYENDSESSION** message (after called **ShutdownBlockReason____** functions) does not prevent shutdown, and handling **Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding** event neither prevents shutdown, but at least this last prevents from logging off... well, it logs off and instantly it relogs the user session (at least in Windows 10), which is a little annonying. My application has a GUI as per requisites described to be able cancel shutdown in the articles you linked. No way.

Comment: Oh, and to be able prevent user log-off by handling **Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding** event firstly I needed to follow these steps: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-automatic-termination-of-applications-during-shutdown-in-windows-7 to create that registry value which didn't existed in my system, but that needs a system restart/log-off to take effect so is not really useful for this, and anyway it does not prevent shutting down on my system, only log-off.

Comment: Maybe the real issue could be what the current system configuration is (maybe a registry value related to shutdown preferences that is denying applications from cancelling a shutdown?, or not showing the UI with the list of those applications when shutting down?), as commented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7685153/1248295 - In that case I need to know which registry value could cause this issue to try fix it at runtime (I mean modify the value) or detect at runtime the problem to advert that the shutdown can't be cancelled due "X" user preference in the system. Any ideas?. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, I started doing a trial-and-error snapshooting in a fresh Virtual Machine with Windows 10 and I discovered what the problem is: If the user has the **AutoEndTasks** registry value set (found in **HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop** registry key), then the shutdown does not show any UI to let the user cancel shutdown, so its useless to create a "cancel shutdown reason" in these circumstances because the app will be forced to close instantly in any case to continue the shutdown.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc978604(v=technet.10)

Comment: So, in order to make this thing to work as expected, the registry data of *AutoEndTasks* registry value must be *0* (zero); otherwise any app that attempts to prevent shutdown will be terminated and no UI will be shown at shutdown. Please add this info to your answer then I can mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you. Another source for reference: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/97821-turn-autoendtasks-restart-shut-down-sign-out-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Note: I discovered that the **AutoEndTasks** value can be added to "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop", that overrides the value established in "HKCU" hive and "HKU\{SID}".

This means, if **AutoEndTasks** is false (0) in "HKCU" but is true (1) in "HKU\.DEFAULT", then the app will not prevent from shutting down and no shutdown UI will be shown.

if **AutoEndTasks** is false in "HKU\.DEFAULT" but is true in "HKCU", then the app will prevent from shutting down and the shutdown UI will be shown.

Comment: Also a good point about this is that the **AutoEndTasks** value does not require to restart/log-off the system to take effect. So, once it is established to false in the proper key  ("HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop"), the app will prevent shut down, and we can revert this value to its previous state when we finish to use the **PreventShutdownContext** class.

That's all. I also ensured that the disabling of important Window Services will not affect this behavior.

Comment: @ElektroStudios, I think you should better move your comments to your own answer. Then you can accept it. It would be unfair to accept my answer because I actually didn't provide any solution.

Comment: Don't worry, the tip about **WM_QUERYENDSESSION** message and the guidelines exposing the requeriments of an application in order to prevent shutdown all that was essential to achieve this.

Comment: @ElektroStudios, I incorporated your research into the answer, as you suggested. You might review it and probably delete the comments to keep the answer clear.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interested, I'm sharing my custom implementation, in VB.NET. Currently this code is missing the Windows API definitions and the method that I'm using to read/write to the **AutoEndTasks** registry value (the member with name `TweakingUtil.AutoEndTasks` in the code below), but you can get the idea which I think is the most important thing about all this...

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Security

''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Provides a mechanism to prevent any system shutdown/restart/log-off request during the life-cycle of a instance of this class.
''' <para></para>
''' Applications should use this class as they begin an operation that cannot be interrupted, such as burning a CD or DVD.
''' <para></para>
''' This class is to be used in either a <see langword="Using"/> statement or for the life-cycle of the current application.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <remarks>
''' Original source-code: <see href="https://github.com/dahall/Vanara/blob/master/WIndows.Forms/Contexts/PreventShutdownContext.cs"/>
''' </remarks>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <example> This is a code example.
''' <code lang="vb">
''' Using psc As New PreventShutdownContext("Critical operation is in progress...")
'''     ' Do something that can't be interrupted... 
''' End Using
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <example> This is a code example.
''' <code lang="vb">
''' Public NotInheritable Class Form1 : Inherits Form
''' 
'''     Private psc As PreventShutdownContext
''' 
'''     Private Sub AllowShutdown()
'''         If (Me.psc IsNot Nothing) Then
'''             Me.psc.Dispose()
'''             Me.psc = Nothing
'''         End If
'''     End Sub
''' 
'''     Private Sub DisallowShutdown()
'''         If (Me.psc Is Nothing) Then
'''             Me.psc = New PreventShutdownContext("Application defined reason goes here.")
'''         End If
'''     End Sub
''' 
'''     Protected Overrides Sub OnShown(ByVal e As EventArgs)
'''         Me.DisallowShutdown()
'''         MyBase.OnShown(e)
'''     End Sub
''' 
''' End Class
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <example> This is a code example using the <see langword="using"/> statement.
''' <code lang="cs">
''' using (new PreventShutdownContext("Critical operation is in progress...")) {
'''    // Do something that can't be interrupted...
''' }
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <code lang="cs">
''' public partial class Form1 : Form {
''' 
'''    private PreventShutdownContext disallowShutdown;
''' 
'''    private void AllowShutdown() {
'''        if (this.psc != null) {
'''            this.psc.Dispose();
'''            this.psc = null;
'''        }
'''    }
'''
'''    private void DisallowShutdown() {
'''        if (this.psc == null) {
'''            this.psc = new PreventShutdownContext("Application defined reason goes here.");
'''        }
'''    }
'''
'''    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
'''        this.DisallowShutdown();
'''        base.OnShown(e);
'''    }
'''    
''' }
''' </code>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public NotInheritable Class PreventShutdownContext : Implements IDisposable

#Region " Private Fields "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Holds the main window handle for the current application.
    ''' </summary>
    Private ReadOnly hRef As HandleRef

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Flag to determine whether the shutdown reason is created.
    ''' </summary>
    Private isReasonCreated As Boolean

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Holds the previous value of "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop" "AutoEndTasks" registry value.
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' This registry value is restored when calling <see cref="PreventShutdownContext.Dispose()"/>
    ''' </summary>
    Private ReadOnly previousAutoEndTasksValue As Boolean

#End Region

#Region " Constructors "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PreventShutdownContext"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="reason">
    ''' The reason for which the current application must prevent system shutdown. 
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' Because users are typically in a hurry when shutting down the system, 
    ''' they may spend only a few seconds looking at the shutdown reasons that are displayed by the system. 
    ''' Therefore, it is important that your reason strings are short and clear.
    ''' </param>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="throwOnError">
    ''' If <see langword="True"/>, an exception will be thrown if 
    ''' the application does not meet the requirements to prevent a system shutdown.
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' Default value is <see langword="True"/>.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
    ''' Applications without a user interface can't prevent a system shutdown.
    ''' </exception>
    ''' 
    ''' <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
    ''' The main window of the current application is not yet created or is not visible.
    ''' </exception>
    ''' 
    ''' <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
    ''' Only the thread that created the main window of the current application can call this to prevent a system shutdown.
    ''' </exception>
    ''' 
    ''' <exception cref="SecurityException">
    ''' The user does not have the permissions required to create or modify 'AutoEndTasks' registry value. 
    ''' Therefore, the application can't prevent a system shutdown.
    ''' </exception>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Sub New(ByVal reason As String, Optional ByVal throwOnError As Boolean = True)

        If Not Environment.UserInteractive Then
            If (throwOnError) Then
                Throw New InvalidOperationException(
                    "Applications without a user interface can't prevent a system shutdown.")
            End If
        End If

        Dim pr As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
        Me.hRef = New HandleRef(pr, pr.MainWindowHandle)
        If (Me.hRef.Handle = IntPtr.Zero) AndAlso (throwOnError) Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException(
                "The main window of the current application is not yet created or is not visible.")
        End If

        Dim currentThreadId As UInteger = NativeMethods.GetCurrentThreadId()
        Dim mainThreadId As Integer = NativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(Me.hRef.Handle, Nothing)
        If (currentThreadId <> mainThreadId) AndAlso (throwOnError) Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException(
                "Only the thread that created the main window of the current application can call this to prevent a system shutdown.")
        End If

        Me.previousAutoEndTasksValue = TweakingUtil.AutoEndTasks
        If (Me.previousAutoEndTasksValue) Then
            Try
                TweakingUtil.AutoEndTasks = False
            Catch ex As SecurityException
                If (throwOnError) Then
                    Throw New SecurityException(
                            "The user does not have the permissions required to create or modify 'AutoEndTasks' registry value. " &
                            "Therefore, the application can't prevent a system shutdown.", ex)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                If (throwOnError) Then
                    Throw
                End If
            End Try
        End If

        AddHandler SystemEvents.SessionEnding, AddressOf Me.SessionEnding
        Me.Reason = reason

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Properties "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the reason for which the current application must prevent system shutdown. 
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' Because users are typically in a hurry when shutting down the system, 
    ''' they may spend only a few seconds looking at the shutdown reasons that are displayed by the system. 
    ''' Therefore, it is important that your reason strings are short and clear.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>
    ''' The reason for which the current application must prevent system shutdown.
    ''' </value>
    Public Property Reason As String
        Get
            Return Me.reason_
        End Get
        <DebuggerStepThrough>
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If value.Equals(Me.reason_, StringComparison.Ordinal) Then
                Exit Property
            End If

            Me.SetReason(value)
            Me.reason_ = value
        End Set
    End Property
    ''' <summary>
    ''' ( backing field of <see cref="PreventShutdownContext.Reason"/> property )
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' The reason for which the application must prevent system shutdown.
    ''' </summary>
    Private reason_ As String

#End Region

#Region " Event-Handlers "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Handles the <see cref="Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding"/> event.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender">
    ''' The source of the event.
    ''' </param>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="e">
    ''' The <see cref="SessionEndingEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.
    ''' </param>
    Private Sub SessionEnding(ByVal sender As Object, e As SessionEndingEventArgs)

        ' By setting "e.Cancel" property to True, 
        ' the application will respond 0 (zero) to "WM_QUERYENDSESSION" message in order to prevent a system shutdown. 
        '
        ' For more info: 
        ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shutdown/wm-queryendsession
        ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Shutdown/shutdown-changes-for-windows-vista

        e.Cancel = True

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Private Methods "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Sets the reason for which the current application must prevent system shutdown.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="reason">
    ''' The reason for which the current application must prevent system shutdown.
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' Because users are typically in a hurry when shutting down the system, 
    ''' they may spend only a few seconds looking at the shutdown reasons that are displayed by the system. 
    ''' Therefore, it is important that your reason strings are short and clear.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <exception cref="Win32Exception">
    ''' </exception>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Private Sub SetReason(ByVal reason As String)
        Dim succeed As Boolean
        Dim win32Err As Integer

        If (Me.isReasonCreated) Then
            succeed = NativeMethods.ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(Me.hRef.Handle)
            win32Err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
            If Not succeed Then
                Throw New Win32Exception(win32Err)
            End If
        End If

        succeed = NativeMethods.ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(Me.hRef.Handle, reason)
        win32Err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
        If Not succeed Then
            Throw New Win32Exception(win32Err)
        End If
        Me.isReasonCreated = True
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " IDisposable Implementation "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Flag to detect redundant calls when disposing.
    ''' </summary>
    Private isDisposed As Boolean

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Releases all the resources used by this instance.
    ''' </summary>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Me.Dispose(isDisposing:=True)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    ''' Releases unmanaged and, optionally, managed resources.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="isDisposing">
    ''' <see langword="True"/>  to release both managed and unmanaged resources; 
    ''' <see langword="False"/> to release only unmanaged resources.
    ''' </param>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Private Sub Dispose(ByVal isDisposing As Boolean)
        If (Not Me.isDisposed) AndAlso (isDisposing) Then
            RemoveHandler SystemEvents.SessionEnding, AddressOf Me.SessionEnding
            NativeMethods.ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(Me.hRef.Handle)
            Me.isReasonCreated = False
            Try
                TweakingUtil.AutoEndTasks = Me.previousAutoEndTasksValue
            Catch
            End Try
        End If

        Me.isDisposed = True
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```